# Pencil brush in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-tablet

I have a Wacom Intuos 3 pen tablet. I bought it so I can naturally draw directly into the computer.

Working in Photoshop, though, I cannot seem to find the brush settings that mostly resemble drawing with a regular pencil (opacity, edge etc...).

Can anybody direct me towards a resource or downloadable brush that will have settings and shape similar to that of a regular, moderately soft pencil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried the [wacom brushes](http://www.wacom.com/intuos/bonus-software.php)?

You might also check out [this blog about pencil brushes](http://cedrichohnstadt.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/photoshop-pencil-brushes/).

Comment: I think you missed the first line in my question: "I have a Wacom Intuos 3 pen tablet."

Comment: I think you missed the fact that Photoshop is not a traditional media simulator, and all the configurable brush parameters are right there in front of you if you don't like the defaults.

Comment: Sass much? I'm asking a simple question here - that's one hell of an agressive comment. This is a friendly community - please participate appropriately.

Comment: Yuval, His comment was probably my fault. I changed my answer after your comment. He most likely didn't see my original answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the brushes are great and your help is much appreciated!